# setTimeout doesn't wanto to make delay on method call

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a class with a method which is instanced as a object. When element is clicked this should call object method. Both calls work. However, I expected 2nd call to have delay of 75000. However, there is no delay at all. It makes second call without any delay. I am using ECMAScript6 here.

```
class Test {
  foo(x){
    switch (x) {
      case 1:
        alert('test1')
      break;
      case 2:
        alert('test2');
      break;
    }
  }
}

var test = new Test();
$('#test-trigger').click(function() {
  test.foo(1);
  setTimeout(test.foo(2),75000)
});
```

Comment: Thats because you're calling `test.foo(2)` straight away.

Comment: _“It makes second call without any delay”_ – _you_ are calling the method directly, because that’s what `()` at the end _does_. You need to pass a function _reference_ to setTimeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function in the `setTimeout` instead of passing function as parameter. You can create a new function (from the old one), bind it and prepend parameter to it with [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
setTimeout(test.foo.bind(test, 2), 75000);
```

Comment: This works, I'll accept your answer as soon as Stackoverflow lets me.

Comment: @Kunok it is important to know why it works.

Comment: Indeed! Now that I read few comments on question and your answer, it is clear to me now.